# Android: reduce the margin of a NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

Is there a way to resize the margin of the `NumberPicker` from the XML ?

Actually it seems impossible.

This is my result, there's a text over the picker but cannot be seen as the margin is too large.

[image]

I tried to rescale it but it just rescales the picture inside, not the whole layout.

```
<NumberPicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleX="0.5"
            android:scaleY="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/numMonth"/>
```

Comment: yes but it resizes also the image and has no effect on the height

Comment: The object's image, + / - buttons

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your are setting the scale to 0.5. set it to 1 or better remove it.

```
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
```

Comment: Of course but I need to resize the image, it's really too large.

Comment: control the layout_height and layout_width. set them values in `dp`

Comment: Come on, do you think I didn't try it ? It just cuts the image

Comment: strectches text. doesnt resize spacing

Answer (score -1):

I was using API 19. 
With API 21 it cannot even be resized so I will create my own object.